# How to get string array value stored in sharedpreference?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

So I store a `string array` to `shared preference`. It is saved like this    :

```
["{action= some text, task= some text}", "{action= some text 2, task= some text 2 }" ]
```

How do I retrieve the string indicated in action and task keys?

Comment: concatenate everything using a comma and store it ,and retreive it using split

Comment: To an extent that looks like a JSON array although the syntax isn't quite the same. Why not just use JSON anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment on your question (which you've now deleted), your string isn't the best way to produce valid JSON...

```
["{action= some text, task= some text}", "{action= some text 2, task= some text 2 }" ]
```

Using JSON, in the above, `action` and `task` look like they should be keys and should be surrounded with quotes, i.e., `"action"` and `"task"`.

In that case, instead of using `=` the key/value pairs should be separated by `:` and assuming `some text` and `some text 2` (the values) are also strings they need to be surrounded by quotes.

Finally a JSON object is not surrounded by quotes so your JSON string should actually look like this...

```
[{"action":"some text", "task":"some text"}, {"action":"some text 2", "task":"some text 2"}]
```

Now, assuming you have a `JSONArray` that represents the above you would save it to SharedPreferences using something like...

```
prefs.edit().putString("json_string", myJsonArray.toString()).commit();
```

...then to retrieve it use...

```
JSONArray myJsonArray = new JSONArray(prefs.getString("json_string", ""));
```

When you've retrieved your JSONArray you can get each JSONObject using...

```
myJsoObject = myJsonArray.getJSONObject(0); // In this case it's index 0 - use a for loop to retrieve all
```

Then you can get `action` and `task` as follows...

```
String actionValue = myJsonObject.getString("action");
String taskValue = myJsonObject.getString("task");
```

Comment: If the string in sharedpreference looks like this:

["{action= some text, task= some text}", "{action= some text 2, task= some text 2 }" ]


how do I extract its contents? Seperating the values of action and task?

Comment: What I was trying to explain is it would be better if you don't store your string in that format. Trying to parse that format of string is not going to be easy and if you say you are using JSON then you're doing it in a very odd way. If my answer is of no help to you then let me know and I'll delete it.